# chrome iOS touchmove event not working

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, canvas

I have the following working in safari on iOS, but in chrome on iOS it doesnt seem to be working. In fact the browser scrolls around so I don't think e.preventDefault is doing it's job.

```
canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", trackPositionTouch, true);

function trackPositionTouch(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = e.targetTouches[0].pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    mouse.y = e.targetTouches[0].pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
}
```

Comment: use touches[0] instead of targetTouches[0]

Comment: @singhiskng just tried that, it made no difference

Comment: I have the same issue with Chrome. Have you been able to find a solution on your own?

Answer (score 0):

It's a better idea to check for both event types. This is how I did it in a project. I am using jQuery to select DOM elements.

```
var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0];

var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();

var relX = (touch.pageX - parentOffset.left);
var relY = (touch.pageY - parentOffset.top);
```